# Taxis from Heathrow with a lot of luggage

Tags: luggage, london, lhr, taxis

I will be arriving in Heathrow around noon with a lot of luggage (around 4 big pieces). Will I find room in taxis to take this to downtown London or should I book something in advance ?

Comment: Where abouts in London are you headed? A black cab from Heathrow to the centre isn't the cheapest thing to get...

Comment: I am going near St Pancras. Which option would you suggest ? Carrying the bags myself in the public transportation is not an option.

Comment: Get a luggage trolley, down to the Heathrow Express, unload the bags onto the HEX, in the dedicated luggage areas, express train to Paddington, grab another luggage trolley from the platform at Paddington, up to the taxi rank there, and taxi along to STP. Should be quicker and cheaper

Comment: Tx for the answer. Regarding prices maybe I should have said that we were two.

Comment: Borderline whether 2 people plus 4 'big' pieces of luggage would fit in a black cab. How big is 'big'?

Comment: Not bigger that what can be checked (without extras)  in an airplane. Also not so "big" but not small

Comment: how heavy your luggage are?

Comment: @AE Several years ago, two of us arrived into Heathrow with 6 large suitcases plus 2 small-ish backpacks plus 2 laptop bags plus a couple more small bits and pieces of luggage - we were moving to UK.  Both of us plus all the luggage had no problem fitting into the black cab.

Comment: @Him about 15 kg each

Comment: @AleksG  Thanks for the info, I am actually in the same situation. I followed the advice in the answer and pre-booked a taxi.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't take a cab, [they're the most expensive in the world](http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02586/study_2586614a.jpg).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taxis that you can get from a taxi rank at the terminal (without booking ahead) are '**black cabs**'. A black cab is *probably* big enough for 2 people plus 4 big bags, but might be a bit of a squeeze (depending on your definition of 'big'). Expect to pay £45 to £85 (depending on traffic) as per https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/taxis-and-minicabs/taxi-fares

You can get a good view of the size of a standard black cab in this video:
http://youtu.be/YzvejjipQy0

Taxis that you can only book ahead of time are '**minicabs**', there's a price comparator here: https://www.minicabit.com/search_trip.php
Expect to pay about £40 - tell them about the luggage in advance so they don't send a vehicle that's too small. If you want a large, reputable minicab firm then you can do worse than Addison Lee: http://www.addisonlee.com/passenger-services/airport-transfers/heathrow-airport-transfers/

**Uber** exists in London and will charge you £53 for an UberXL vehicle from Heathrow to central London as per https://www.uber.com/cities/london

Personally, I'd get the **Heathrow Express** train to London Paddington and get a taxi from Paddington, it'll be cheaper (if you book tickets far enough ahead for the HE) and also quicker than a taxi all the way from Heathrow. (Traffic coming from Heathrow to Central London can be pretty terrible). It's pretty easy to get luggage on and off the HE, it's a large modern train designed to serve the airport. Step-free access, plenty of luggage space, enough time to load luggage, etc. https://www.heathrowexpress.com/tickets-deals/prices-fares
Heathrow Express ticket prices start at £6.99 per person (if you book 3 months ahead), a taxi from Paddington to St Pancras should take about 10-15 mins and cost 10-15 pounds. HE journey time Heathrow->Paddington is 15 mins, trains leave every 15 mins.
https://www.heathrowexpress.com/timetable-schedule/heathrow-london
If you're coming from terminal 4 then you have to change trains, otherwise you don't.

You are absolutely right not to take 4 large suitcases on the Tube (London Underground), but the Heathrow Express is a different kettle of fish entirely.

Enjoy your trip!

Comment: My view is that they'd fit in a black cab if you're not paying excess luggage at check-in. Remember that the space where a passenger seat in the front would normally be is available for luggage, plus the area where the other 3 people a black cab can take would sit. Note that black cabs charge extra for lots of luggage.

Comment: Yeah, @ablligh is probably right.

Comment: Just a note: several years ago, two of us arrived into Heathrow with 6 large suitcases plus 2 small-ish backpacks plus 2 laptop bags plus a couple more small bits and pieces of luggage - we were moving to UK.  Both of us plus all the luggage had no problem fitting into the black cab.

Comment: Agree that it should fit in a black cab, have done so a few times, though it might get a bit cramped. Note that there are now "new generation" black cabs which are much larger (Mercedes mini-vans), and there should be no issue at all in those. If it won't fit in a regular black cab, just stay on the side of the queue at the taxi rank and wait for such a taxi to come, it shouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 2):

In your shoes I would get a pre-booked taxi service. You'll be able to put one or two bags on the back seat if they don't fit in the boot. If there is more than one of you travelling, you should say that you have a lot of luggage and a bigger vehicle will be provided.