# Arriving in Heathrow Airport in London with 5 large bags plus a large music keyboard

Tags: luggage, london, lhr

I am arriving at Heathrow Airport in London with 5 large bags and a very large music keyboard.

What would be the best way to go to East London from there?

One of the trick points is that 3 of the bags and the keyboard will be in the cargo area of the airport. So we have to get the bags from the flight and then collect the rest before heading to East London.

We are thinking between hiring a large SUV and dropping it in East London somewhere or maybe UberXL. Or? Thanks for any idea!

Comment: The Cargo area is a short + free bus ride from T5, but largely not near anything itself. I'd lean towards free bus from T5 to there with 2 bags, collect others, then large pre-booked minicab onwards. Uber drivers in London are generally lovely, but unable to find their own feet with a map and a satnav... Driving in London is not usually recommended, let alone having lust flown in!

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57303/taxis-from-heathrow-with-a-lot-of-luggage

Comment: How many people is "we" ?

Comment: I would use a service based out of East London. It's likely to be a lot cheaper than renting.

Comment: we are 2 people.