# Do I prebook a taxi from Heathrow to London King's Cross?

Tags: uk, transportation, bookings, lhr, taxis

Is it cheaper to prebook a taxi from Heathrow to get to King's Cross station, or better to find a taxi waiting at the airport? We're flying in from New Zealand.

Comment: While you don't mention luggage, does this: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57303/taxis-from-heathrow-with-a-lot-of-luggage answer your question? Broadly speaking pre-booked  "private hire"/"minicab" will be cheaper than a taxi ("black cab") you pick up at the airport. But if you are getting on a train at KGX, you might just be better off getting the tube.

Comment: @CMaster That question is about how to get there by any means. The answers don't compare prices of pre-booked and non-pre-booked taxis, because that's not what is asked. This question is specifically about taxis. "Which type of taxi is cheaper" / "The tube is £5.50" whut?

Comment: This is not really a dupe - the person is asking specifically for taxis and not what are the options to get from Heathrow to King's Cross.

Comment: Not a dupe but, still, getting the Picadilly line would be much cheaper. Should be fine with luggage unless travelling in rush hours.

Comment: I'm getting really tired of linking to this now... [Can we be more careful in marking duplicates on questions that are related but ask for or about different things?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3482/can-we-be-more-careful-in-marking-duplicates-on-questions-that-are-related-but-a) It's getting completely absurd how often people [keep doing the same thing](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/another-question-closed-wrongly-complaint)

Comment: Use Uber. No need to pre-book anything and you're guaranteed a fair price.

Comment: I would consider this a dupe. The two OPs both have exactly the same problem - they want to get from Heathrow Airport to Kings Cross. Answering this question without mentioning the Piccadilly line would be a disservice to the OP who may have the [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/219993). Likewise, the specific information about what type of taxi to take would be helpful on the other question. Surely having two questions is worse than having one here?

Comment: Hi Piet.  I interpreted your Q **about a taxi** as meaning you specifically want a taxi.  So I'm assuming you want to avoid (A) the huge PITA of getting to the train at Heathrow (B) the idea of dragging around lots of luggage/family on train(s) (C) the fact you have to take a taxi again anyway at the other end to get to where you're actually going (hotel?)  Re the question in your **headline**, NO, you can absolutely walk right up and get a Black Cab with total convenience and no prebooking.  Re the question in your text, it is CHEAPER to prebook some sort of taxi.

Comment: @user568458 I've created a canonical question on London taxis, so that we can put all the info in one place: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73249/what-are-the-taxi-options-in-london

Comment: @JonathanReez You guys are obsessed.

Comment: @MartinSmith But if travelling in rush hours, it will not be pleasant with luggage, even if you already have a seat. I take the tube to work at rush hours, and I have never seen such anger shown by London commuters as is shown to the poor soul trying to take an oversized case through the underground at peak time.

Comment: @Calchas did you miss the word "unless"?

Comment: @MartinSmith I did not. But I thought it worth stressing, that taking luggage through the underground at rush hour is really to be avoided.

Answer (score 19):

If you haven't already, [do consider public transport options](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16960/how-to-get-from-heathrow-airport-to-kings-cross-london) which are very good and start *much* cheaper. If you take Heathrow Express then the tube, it's likely to be a little faster than a taxi; if you take the Piccadilly Line, as well as being very cheap, you don't need to change trains so it's still quite convenient (and might even be faster than a taxi if traffic is bad).

---

If you don't mind paying extra and want a taxi for the convenience, and don't mind risking being stuck in traffic:

**It's definitely cheaper to pre-book.** Much cheaper. Simple economics: if you just turn up, you're a captive market, if you shop around, there's competition. London is a monster that lives and thrives on eating the wallets of people who didn't plan ahead; if you do plan ahead though, it can be surprisingly cheap.

The first private hire result from googling "Heathrow taxis" gives a quote for **£51**. I won't link to it because I recommend shopping around and checking reviews, it's just to give you an idea. [Uber](https://www.uber.com/cities/london/) starts even cheaper - estimates start at £33. **Important note:** locating your private hire driver might not be as straightforward at Heathrow as it could be due to Heathrow's rules, [see djna's answer on this page for details](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/73327/3145).

I've never taken a just-turn-up taxi from a London airport but [an answer here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16960/how-to-get-from-heathrow-airport-to-kings-cross-london) estimates them at **£80** and I'm surprised at how cheap that is. [TaxiFareFinder](https://www.taxifarefinder.com/main.php?city=London&from=Heathrow+Airport%2C+Longford%2C+United+Kingdom&to=Kings+Cross%2C+London%2C+United+Kingdom&fromCoord=51.4700223,-0.4542954999999438&toCoord=51.5333335,-0.13223119999997834) estimates it at **between £68.83 and £122.07** depending on traffic, and I'd expect it to be towards the upper end given how congested that route tends to be. That said, there will *definitely* be a black cab in the taxi rank (there's always a small risk a private hire car might be late, fail to arrive, etc), and for the extra money you do get convenience and a driver who's passed ["the knowledge" test](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/11/10/t-magazine/london-taxi-test-knowledge.html) and knows a *heck* of a lot about London (a private hire driver might be a new arrival following a satnav).

---

I notice you mention King's Cross - if you're taking a train, intercity trains in the UK are also usually much cheaper if you book them a few days in advance. It depends on the route, some it doesn't make much or sometimes any difference at all, but for others (particularly trains up north from King's Cross to Newcastle, Edinburgh etc) booking ahead can save you 75% or more. It's sometimes also a bit of a lottery depending on how many tickets are sold, so get in early if it's a long journey.

Answer (score 4):

I've never taken a taxi from LHR to London/King's Cross. Picadilly is the way to go and I agree with others that's it's relatively easy as tube basically starts at LHR so it's fairly empty.  I've also taken Heathrow Express which is faster.  Taxi is the last resort, more expensive and can take longer due to traffic.

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of repetition: Picadilly line tube is by far the cheapest option, requires no changes and at peak times is likely to be much faster. The roads into London can be very, very slow in the morning rush hour. As the trains start at Heathrow you should have no trouble getting a seat.

Taxis: be aware of one important thing, there is no designated pick-up area for booked taxis, taxis (and indeed private cars) are not permitted to stop at the drop-off areas and wait for customers. This rule is enforced with increased rigour these days. Hence your choices are:

a). Use the standard Black Taxi service. Orderly queues, regulated cabs, drivers have "the knowledge" and so know the routes and hotels; this is relatively expensive.

b). Book a taxi through one of many cab services, but verify how you will locate your driver. I'd advise against using any firm that will not have you met at the exit from the customs hall. Some firms may try to save parking fees by asking you to go up to the drop off areas, but you can easily end up playing dodge-the-policeman and waiting for your driver. This is very annoying when you are tired after a long flight. Your driver should pay for parking and either come to meet you (by far my preferred option) or state some very well-defined meeting point in the car park. You should expect to have the parking fee (£5 or more) added to your fare. All the cab firms should take your flight details and adjust their arrival times according to your actual schedule. You really need to have a UK cell-phone available as your driver may have trouble finding you.

Comment: +1 Very good point! If convenience is the #1 priority and cost isn't much of a a factor I suppose there is a case for paying extra for a black cab from the taxi rank. There's also the fact that there's a small risk the private hire might be late or not show up.

Comment: Yes, private hire is somewhat less reliable, but considerably cheaper. I've only ever had one private hire fail to turn up and a couple be late in many years of business travel.